# Librosa spectrogram with empty area

Tags: python, audio, librosa, audio-processing, spectrogram

I use the following code to plot the spectrogram of an audio file by using `librosa`.

```
y, sr = librosa.load(filename)

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=100, frameon=False)

D = librosa.stft(y)  # STFT of y
S_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(D), ref=np.max)
librosa.display.specshow(S_db)

plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)

plt.margins(0,0)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())

plt.axis('off')

plt.savefig(output_file, dpi=100, pad_inches=0)
```

The following pictures show the output of two audio files extracted from two different datasets. As you can see, the purple lines occupy approximately 1/3 of the whole image, while in the second they cover almost the entire picture.

I thought that it is due to different sampling rate, so I checked it.
The first dataset is sampled at 22KHz, while the second at 44.1KHz.
However, if I downsample the audio files from the second dataset by using `fibrosa.load(filename, sr=22000)` the resulting image doesn't change.

Any suggestions?

[image: 234234]

<sup>*Spectrogram image from the first dataset.*</sup>

[image: asd]

<sup>*Spectrogram image from the second dataset.*</sup>

Comment: Are you certain there's energy in the higher end of the spectrum? Also, if you plot the first one separately, does it exhibit the same feature? `matplotlib` has sometimes counter-intuitive behaviour, maintaining state in less-than-obvious fashion.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski honestly, I have no idea. This is the first time that I'm dealing with audio file. What should I check? Can you give me an advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there's no energy in the higher end of the spectrum, because of either characteristic of that audio or, more likely, low pass filter being applied, that's what you would see. Open the audio in e.g. Audacity and check the spectrum. You can also link both audio here and I will have a look.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski thank you very much for your help! I uploaded two files here (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19Z83Fk8ToEZ0vMcFFdJomZTpXwQ-tlcv?usp=sharing): file1.wav comes from the first dataset, while file2.wav comes from the second.

Comment: Thanks - need access though.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I gave you access to the files. Any clues?